# What song is playing at the end of this Family Guy segment?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

In the following clip [Fox’s ‘Family Guy’ Perfectly Mocks PC Social Justice Warriors on Twitter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__l6alNQsnI), a song starts playing at the 2 minute mark.

We just hear the music and no lyrics. The music rings a bell, but I just can't put my finger on the name of the song. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

It was [Lynyrd Skynyrd's *Free Bird*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np0solnL1XY).